# Incompatible data

Tags: c

What is wrong in that code ?
I get error "Semantic Issue: Passing 'cards [3]' to parameter of incompatible type 'cards'"

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char *name;
    int sequence
} cards;

void print_deck(cards data);

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    cards deck[] = 
    {
        {"Heart", 1},
        {"Arrow", 2},
        {"Spatiq", 3}  
    };

    print_deck(deck);

    return 0;
}

void print_deck(cards data) {

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to pass `deck`, which is an *array* of cards, to a function with a parameter of type `cards`. Those are two different types. You probably want to change the type of the parameter in the `print_deck` function. I'd also suggest renaming the `cards` type as it's only actually a single card.

Comment: in that case how print_deck() definition should look ?

Comment: @user1089415: you'd need something like `void print_deck(cards data[])` - although you don't then know the length of the array. You may want to have a terminator value, or pass in the length, or something like that.

Comment: *"a method with a function of type cards"* doesn't make sense. I suggest, *"a function with parameter type `cards`"*

Comment: @Pubby: Whoops, yes. Originally it was "a method with parameter type `cards`", then I remembered that they're called functions in C, but changed the wrong word. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

`deck` is an array of `cards`, while `print_deck()` expects to get a `cards` type, those are incompatible types.

You probably want to declare `print_deck()` as: `print_deck(cards deck[],int size)` [where size indicates how big is your array of cards]

Answer (score 0):

Your function only has an interface to receive one single card and not an array. Use something like `print_deck(deck[0]);`